# parallel loop for with multiple parameters and using iteration number

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrent.futures

I have a function with a for loop inside. I would like to get it to run in multiple parallel processes.

The function gets multiple parameters and in the for loop I used the iteration number of the loop.

But it doesn't recognize the `i` (iteration of the loop).

What it the best way to do this parallel?

**Code without parallel:**

```py
sum = 0
def BRANCH1(param1, param2, param3):
  for i in range(0, brnchs):
    sum = sum + i + param2 + param3

def BRANCH1(param1, param2, param3):
  sum = sum + i + param2 + param3
```

**Code with parallel:**

```py
func = partial(BRANCH1, param1, param2, param3)
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
  executor.map(func, branches)
```

Comment: Do not use `sum` as a name of variable, you're shadowing important built-in function. And using global variable in concurrent execution is not the best idea too.

Comment: Your code seems quite incomplete. You overwrite the function `BRANCH1` in your non-parallel example. Could you post a full, runnable example of the non-parallel code?